# Convolve2d just by using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix, convolution

I am studying image-processing using NumPy and facing a problem with filtering with convolution.

**I would like to convolve a gray-scale image. (convolve a 2d Array with a smaller 2d Array)**

Does anyone have an idea to **refine** my method?

I know that [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) supports convolve2d but I want to make a convolve2d only by using NumPy.

## What I have done

First, I made a 2d array the submatrices.

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5) # original matrix

submatrices = np.array([
     [a[:-2,:-2], a[:-2,1:-1], a[:-2,2:]],
     [a[1:-1,:-2], a[1:-1,1:-1], a[1:-1,2:]],
     [a[2:,:-2], a[2:,1:-1], a[2:,2:]]])
```

the submatrices seems complicated but what I am doing is shown in the following drawing.

[image: submatrices]

Next, I multiplied each submatrices with a filter.

```
conv_filter = np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,4,-1],[0,-1,0]])
multiplied_subs = np.einsum('ij,ijkl->ijkl',conv_filter,submatrices)
```

[image: multiplied_subs]

and summed them.

```
np.sum(np.sum(multiplied_subs, axis = -3), axis = -3)
#array([[ 6,  7,  8],
#       [11, 12, 13],
#       [16, 17, 18]])
```

Thus this procedure can be called my convolve2d.

```
def my_convolve2d(a, conv_filter):
    submatrices = np.array([
         [a[:-2,:-2], a[:-2,1:-1], a[:-2,2:]],
         [a[1:-1,:-2], a[1:-1,1:-1], a[1:-1,2:]],
         [a[2:,:-2], a[2:,1:-1], a[2:,2:]]])
    multiplied_subs = np.einsum('ij,ijkl->ijkl',conv_filter,submatrices)
    return np.sum(np.sum(multiplied_subs, axis = -3), axis = -3)
```

However, I find this my_convolve2d troublesome for 3 reasons.

1. Generation of the submatrices is too awkward that is difficult to read and can only be used when the filter is 3*3
2. The size of the variant submatrices seems to be too big, since it is approximately 9 folds bigger than the original matrix.
3. The summing seems a little non intuitive. Simply said, ugly.

Thank you for reading this far.

Kind of update. I wrote a conv3d for myself. I will leave this as a public domain.

```
def convolve3d(img, kernel):
    # calc the size of the array of submatrices
    sub_shape = tuple(np.subtract(img.shape, kernel.shape) + 1)

    # alias for the function
    strd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

    # make an array of submatrices
    submatrices = strd(img,kernel.shape + sub_shape,img.strides * 2)

    # sum the submatrices and kernel
    convolved_matrix = np.einsum('hij,hijklm->klm', kernel, submatrices)

    return convolved_matrix
```

Comment: thank you for providing drawings of the matrices :) If I understand correctly, you want tips on how to make your solution more elegant?

Comment: Glad it helps!  Yes. I would be grateful if you can provide me tips to overcome the 3 problems written in the very last lines.

Comment: I should add that the 3 points are rather arranged in a priority order. The first one is quite important for me and the last one seems kinda trivial. I will also be glad if there are other problems and refinements about it.

Comment: Isn't the second drawing (after the equality sign) wrong? Shouldn't each submatrix be multiplied (element-wise) with the filter, and then the elements of each of the resulting submatrices summed?

Comment: @AndyK They will produce the same result.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could generate the subarrays using [`as_strided`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414673/in-numpy-how-to-efficiently-list-all-fixed-size-submatrices):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

sub_shape = (3,3)
view_shape = tuple(np.subtract(a.shape, sub_shape) + 1) + sub_shape
strides = a.strides + a.strides

sub_matrices = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,view_shape,strides)
```

To get rid of your second "ugly" sum, alter your `einsum` so that the output array only has `j` and `k`. This implies your second summation.

```
conv_filter = np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,5,-1],[0,-1,0]])
m = np.einsum('ij,ijkl->kl',conv_filter,sub_matrices)

# [[ 6  7  8]
#  [11 12 13]
#  [16 17 18]]
```

Comment: if a_s is the strided array and filter is your laplacian like filter, then try...  np.sum(a_s*filter, axis=(2,3))  if indeed your answer is array([[ 6,  7,  8],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [16, 17, 18]])

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am trying this myself right now. Maybe trivial but I believe that the name filter is not appropriate because it is a built-in function of python.

Comment: You can do the summation directly in the Einstein summation. See answer

Comment: In this question, isn't it better to write, `sub_shape = conv_filter.shape` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem that it would necessarily be the case.  `conv_filter.shape` should be `a.shape - sub_shape + 1`.  It just so happens in your example `a.shape = [5, 5]` and `sub_shape = (3, 3)` so `conv_filter.shape == sub_shape` is true but not strictly enforced.  If you *want* it to be enforced, then you should set `sub_shape = a.shape - conv_filter.shape + 1`

Comment: Got it! So `view_shape = conv_filter.shape`?

Comment: well `view_shape` should be a 4D tuple, so `view.shape = tuple(conv_filter.shape) + tuple(sub_shape)`, so you still need to find `sub_shape`

Comment: Follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580013/pure-numpy-2d-mean-convolution-derivative-of-input-image

Comment: I have a similar issue for higher dimensions. I was wondering if you could be so kind to take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794274/convolution-of-numpy-arrays-of-arbitrary-dimension-for-cauchy-product-of-multiva)

Comment: Is using `einsum("ij,klij", ...)` sufficient/better?  Using the code from this answer with input of different shape, I got `operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes`, using `"ij,klij"` seems to work without issues.

Answer (score 20):

Cleaned up using `as_strided` and @Crispin 's `einsum` trick from above. Enforces the filter size into the expanded shape.  Should even allow non-square inputs if the indices are compatible.

```
def conv2d(a, f):
    s = f.shape + tuple(np.subtract(a.shape, f.shape) + 1)
    strd = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    subM = strd(a, shape = s, strides = a.strides * 2)
    return np.einsum('ij,ijkl->kl', f, subM)
```

Comment: simplify further... see my comment below...  np.sum(a_s * filter, axis=(2,3)) if indeed your answer is array([[ 6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13], [16, 17, 18]])  ... where a_s is strided array and filter is the 3x3 filter

Comment: Not sure why that works @NaN since it is certainly *not* doing what the problem asked - but it does, even for arbitrary `a` matrices

Comment: at least at numpy v12, a.shape and f.shape is a tuple so `s` should be `tuple(np.subtract(a.shape, f.shape)+1)`, I think.

Comment: True!  Still used to `shape` giving an `ndarray`.  Fixed that.

Comment: Hi @DanielF, is there a generalization of this that works for RGB? Not super familiar with einsum notation, so an idea how to generalize would be awesome.

Comment: @sirgogo, I suggest asking a seperate question linking this answer.  There are people watching `numpy` way better at multidimensional convlcutions than I am.

Comment: @DanielF, thanks, here is the more general version of what I'm trying to do: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239641/multi-dimensional-batch-image-convolution-using-numpy]

Comment: is the kernel flipped here or is it without flipping?

Answer (score 18):

You can also use fft (one of the faster methods to perform convolutions)

```
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2
import numpy as np

def fft_convolve2d(x,y):
    """ 2D convolution, using FFT"""
    fr = fft2(x)
    fr2 = fft2(np.flipud(np.fliplr(y)))
    m,n = fr.shape
    cc = np.real(ifft2(fr*fr2))
    cc = np.roll(cc, -m/2+1,axis=0)
    cc = np.roll(cc, -n/2+1,axis=1)
    return cc
```

- https://gist.github.com/thearn/5424195
- you must pad the filter to be the same size as image ( place it in the middle of a zeros_like mat.)

cheers,
Dan

Comment: It is certainly not efficient to use the FFT for convolution if the kernel has only 9 elements. This is only useful for large kernels.

Comment: True. It depends on the kernel and image size but the threshold for fft to outperform is very low. It also depends on your computer architecture but for most generic use-cases fft is the go to in high performance libraries.

Comment: The following article compares the performance of various image convolution methods, and thus, we can conclude that the FFT method of Numpy is the fastest method to perform convolution.

https://laurentperrinet.github.io/sciblog/posts/2017-09-20-the-fastest-2d-convolution-in-the-world.html

Comment: Regarding the padding: Would simply adding `s=x.shape` to fr2 do the trick?
As in `fr2 = fft2(np.flipud(np.fliplr(y)), s=x.shape) # Pad the filter`

Answer (score 0):

https://laurentperrinet.github.io/sciblog/posts/2017-09-20-the-fastest-2d-convolution-in-the-world.html

Check out all the convolution methods and their respective performances here.
Also, I found the below code snippet to be simpler.

```
from numpy.fft  import fft2, ifft2
def np_fftconvolve(A, B):
    return np.real(ifft2(fft2(A)*fft2(B, s=A.shape)))
```

Comment: This code is not correct. It will shift the output image. The larger the kernel, the larger the shift.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how will it shift the output image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877892/convolving-image-with-kernel-in-fourier-domain/54977551#54977551