# Pure NumPy 2D mean convolution derivative of input image

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have `b` 2d `m x n` greyscale images that I'm convolving with a `p x q` filter and then doing mean-pooling on. With pure numpy, I'd like to compute the derivative of the input image and the filter, but I'm having trouble computing the derivative of the input image:

```
def conv2d_derivatives(x, f, dy):
    """
    dimensions:
        b = batch size
        m = input image height
        n = input image width
        p = filter height
        q = filter width
        r = output height
        s = output width

    input:
        x = input image                       (b x m x n)
        f = filter                            (p x q)
        dy = derivative of some loss w.r.t. y (b x r x s)

    output:
        df = derivative of loss w.r.t. f      (p x q)
        dx = derivative of loss w.r.t. x      (b x m x n)

    notes:
        wx = windowed version of x s.t. wx[b, r, s] = the window of x to compute y[b, r, s]
        vdx = a view of dx 
    """
    b, m, n = x.shape
    p, q = f.shape
    r = m - p + 1
    s = n - q + 1
    wx = as_strided(x, (b, r, s, p, q), np.array([m * n, 1, q, 1, n]) * x.itemsize)

    # This derivative is correct
    df = 1 / (p * q) * np.einsum('brspq,brs->pq', wx, dy)

    # Method 1: this derivative is incorrect
    dx = np.zeros_like(x)
    vdx = as_strided(dx, (b, r, s, p, q), np.array([m * n, 1, q, 1, n]) * dx.itemsize)
    np.einsum('pq,brs->brspq', f, dy, out=vdx)
    dx /= (p * q)

    # Method 2: this derivative is correct, but it's slow and memory-intensive
    dx = np.zeros_like(x)
    vdx = as_strided(dx, (b, r, s, p, q), np.array([m * n, 1, q, 1, n]) * dx.itemsize)
    prod = f[None, None, None, :, :] * dy[:, :, :, None, None]
    for index in np.ndindex(*vdx.shape):
        vdx[index] += prod[index]
    dx /= (p * q)

    return df, dx
```

I know that the derivative of the loss w.r.t. `w[b,r,s,p,q]` is just `1/(p*q) * f[p,q] * dy[b,r,s]`. However, I don't want to explicitly compute the derivatives for `w` and store them in memory because that array would be massive.

I thought I could do an einsum of a view of `dx`, `vdx`, similar to the windowed `wdx`, and hope that einsum would increment `vdx[b,r,s,p,q] += f[p,q] * dy[b,r,s]`, but it actually assigns `vdx[b,r,s,p,q] = f[p,q] * dy[b,r,s]`. If there was a way to specify `out_add_to` in einsum, then my problem would be solved.

How do I compute `dx` without storing a large `b x r x s x p x q` matrix in pure NumPy? I can't use scipy or any other dependency for this problem.

Comment: Holy [Einstellung effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellung_effect) building `vdx` with `as_strided`.  You never want to write to an `as_strided` view , as pointed out in the [notes for `as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html).  What was the intended output of that `einsum` statement?  A toy input and output would be very helpful.

Comment: @DanielF Well, it's possible to do without `as_strided`, but it means I'd probably have to store the entire `prod` array in memory, which is too big for my purposes. I've added a second method, which computes the derivative correctly, but is too slow and memory-intensive. Hope it helps

Comment: Well, you could expand your `f` to a full -sized `(r, s, m, n)` array and `einsum` that, but that's likely an even bigger memory hog without `scipy.sparse`.  I've also played around with using `as_strided` on an `arange(b*m*n)` and using that as a basis for a `np.add.at` approach, but you still end up needing the whole `w` array (although that method would make splitting things up in batches and running them through a `for` loop easier).  Hope that helps, I have to work on other stuff :)

Comment: @michaelsnowden Could you please share your complete code with me for derivative of convolutions as I too need to implement for deep learning model?