# Will results of numpy.as_strided depend on input dtype?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Will the results of [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) depend on the dtype of the NumPy array?

This question arises from the definition of `.strides`, which is

> Tuple of bytes to step in each dimension when traversing an array.

Take the following function that I've used in other questions here.  It takes a 1d or 2d array and creates overlapping windows of length `window`.  The result will one dimension greater than the input.

```
def rwindows(a, window):
    if a.ndim == 1:
        a = a.reshape(-1, 1)
    shape = a.shape[0] - window + 1, window, a.shape[-1]
    strides = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    windows = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    return np.squeeze(windows)

# examples
# rwindows(np.arange(5), window=2)
# rwindows(np.arange(20).reshape((5,4)), window=2)
```

Because of the definition of strides and because, for instance, **otherwise equivalent arrays of dtype `float32` and `float64` will have different strides**, will this ever blow up my `rwindows` function above?

I've tried to test but it's been in a non-exhaustive way and am looking for an answer that (1) explains whether the disclaimer/warning from the function doc has anything to do with what I'm asking here and (2) explains why or why not otherwise-equivalent arrays with different dtypes & strides would yield different results in the above.

Comment: I've seen two problems.  If the shape isn't right, you can end up 'striding' off the end of the buffer.  There's no safeguard to ensure all indexed values are valid.  Secondly, many operations on the strided array make a copy.  That copy could be much larger than the original array or the strided view; that's especially true with multidimensional striding (2 or 3d windows).

Comment: Huh. Looks like that function got popular enough that they're actually documenting it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the warning for `as_strided` is for two issues not really related to the size of the data and more result from writing to the resulting view.

1. First, there is no protection to assure `view = as_strided(a . . . )` *only* points to memory in `a`.  This is why there is so much deliberate preparation work done before calling `as_strided`.  If your algorithm is off, you can easily have your `view` point to memory that is not in `a`, and which may indeed be addressed to garbage, other variables, or your operating system.  If you then write to that view, your data can be lost, misplaced, corrupted . . . or crash your computer.

For your specific example, how safe it is depends a lot on what inputs you're using.  You've set `strides` with `a.strides` so that is dynamic.  You may want to `assert` that the `dtype` of `a` isn't something weird like `object`.

If you're sure that you will *always* have a 2-d `a` that is larger than `window`, you will probably be fine with your algorithm, but you can also `assert` that to make sure.  If not, you may want to make sure that the `as_strided` output works for n-d `a` arrays.  For instance:

```
shape = a.shape[0] - window + 1, window, a.shape[-1]
```

Should probably be

```
shape = (a.shape[0] - window + 1, window) + a.shape[1:]
```

in order to accept n-d input.  It would *probably* never be a problem as far as referencing bad memory, but the current `shape` would reference the wrong data in `a` if you had more dimensions.

2. Second, the view created references the same data blocks multiple times.  If you then do a parallel write to that view (through `view = foo` or `bar( . . ., out = view)`), the results can be [unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45580013/pure-numpy-2d-mean-convolution-derivative-of-input-image) and probably not what you expect.

That said, if you are afraid of problems and don't need to write to the `as_strided` view (as you don't for most convolution applications where it is commonly used), you can always set it as `writable = False`, which will prevent both problems even if your `strides` and/or `shape` are incorrect.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by @hpaulj, in addition to those two problems, if you do something to a `view` that makes a copy (like `.flatten()` or fancy indexing a large chunk of it), it can cause a `MemoryError`.