# Splitting nd-array to sub nd-array with overlapping

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have the an image represented in nd-array. Let's assume that the shape of it is `(256, 256, 3)`.

I wish to slice the image to sub arrays each of size `(128, 128, 3)` with a stride of 64.

I did the following to get the desired indices:

```
for x1, x2 in (zip(range(0, 257, 64), range(128, 257, 64))):
    for y1, y2 in (zip(range(0, 257, 64), range(128, 257, 64))):
        print("rows:",x1,x2,", columns:",y1,y2)
```

I get the following indices to slice:

```
rows: 0 128 , columns: 0 128
rows: 0 128 , columns: 64 192
rows: 0 128 , columns: 128 256
rows: 64 192 , columns: 0 128
rows: 64 192 , columns: 64 192
rows: 64 192 , columns: 128 256
rows: 128 256 , columns: 0 128
rows: 128 256 , columns: 64 192
rows: 128 256 , columns: 128 256
```

Now I can slice each sub array and stack it, moreover, I will want to stack the slices again after some operations on each sub-array and averaging the values.

I was wondering if there is a smarter way of doing it to be able to use it for multiple strides/image sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `skimage.util.view_as_windows`

```
arr = np.random.rand(256, 256, 3)
out = skimage.util.view_as_windows(arr, window_shape = (128, 128, 3), step = 64).squeeze()
print(out.shape)
Out[]: (3, 3, 128, 128, 3)
```

That's a `(3, 3)` array of your `(128, 128, 3)` image patches.

You can also use my (admittedly outdated since `view_as_windows` was implemented for nD) custom recipe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960192/using-numpy-as-strided-function-to-create-patches-tiles-rolling-or-sliding-w/45960193#45960193) which might be helpful if you only have `numpy`

Comment: In case I want to combine the images later, is there a smart way of doing so?

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine'?

Comment: to overlay each array to the "right" position it was taken from. Does it make sense?

Comment: Not really.  The data is still in the "right" position as it is, this is just view on the original data, not a copy.  But writing *into* the view is a [one-way ticket to a race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45812234/4427777), and both my recipe and `view_as_windows` try to prevent that.  In any case, once you know what you want to do with it you can post another question.