# Convolving image with kernel in Fourier domain

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, fft, convolution

I'm using zero padding around my image and convolution kernel, converting them to the Fourier domain, and inverting them back to get the convolved image, see code below. The result, however, is wrong. I was expecting a blurred image, but the output is four shifted quarters. Why is the output wrong, and how can I fix the code?

Input image:

[image: input image]

Result of convolution:

[image: output image]

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageOps,ImageFilter
import numpy as np 
from scipy import fftpack
from copy import deepcopy
import imageio
## STEP 1 ##
im1=Image.open("pika.jpeg")
im1=ImageOps.grayscale(im1)
im1.show()
print("s",im1.size)
## working on this image array
im_W=np.array(im1).T
print("before",im_W.shape)
if(im_W.shape[0]%2==0):
im_W=np.pad(im_W, ((1,0),(0,0)), 'constant')
if(im_W.shape[1]%2==0):
im_W=np.pad(im_W, ((0,0),(1,0)), 'constant')
print("after",im_W.shape)
Boxblur=np.array([[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9],[1/9,1/9,1/9]])
dim=Boxblur.shape[0]

##padding before frequency domain multipication
pad_size=(Boxblur.shape[0]-1)/2
pad_size=int(pad_size)
##padded the image(starts here)

p_im=np.pad(im_W, ((pad_size,pad_size),(pad_size,pad_size)), 'constant')
t_b=(p_im.shape[0]-dim)/2
l_r=(p_im.shape[1]-dim)/2
t_b=int(t_b)
l_r=int(l_r)

##padded the image(ends here)

## padded the kernel(starts here)
k_im=np.pad(Boxblur, ((t_b,t_b),(l_r,l_r)), 'constant')
print("hjhj",k_im)
print("kernel",k_im.shape)

##fourier transforms image and kernel
fft_im = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(p_im))
fft_k  = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft2(k_im))
con_in_f=fft_im*fft_k
ifft2 = abs(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(con_in_f)))
convolved=(np.log(abs(ifft2))* 255 / np.amax(np.log(abs(ifft2)))).astype(np.uint8)
final=Image.fromarray(convolved.T)
final.show()
u=im1.filter(ImageFilter.Kernel((3,3), [1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9,1/9], scale=None, offset=0))
u.show()
```

Comment: Looking at your code, you want to remove all other fft shifts you do there (you need only the one I indicated), they are redundant. I also see a `log` that I don’t know why is there, it will change your colors.

Comment: when we are zero padding, is the kernel supposed to be in the centre or the top left corner, I'm confused as to how to convert a kernel in spatial domain to frequency domain specifically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Discrete Fourier transform (DFT) and, by extension, the FFT (which computes the DFT) have the origin in the first element (for an image, the top-left pixel) for *both* the input and the output. This is the reason we often use the `fftshift` function on the output, so as to shift the origin to a location more familiar to us (the middle of the image).

This means that we need to transform a 3x3 uniform weighted blurring kernel to look like this before passing it to the FFT function:

```
1/9  1/9  0  0  ... 0  1/9
1/9  1/9  0  0  ... 0  1/9
  0    0  0  0  ... 0    0
...  ...               ...
  0    0  0  0  ... 0    0
1/9  1/9  0  0  ... 0  1/9
```

That is, the middle of the kernel (its origin) is at the top-left corner of the image, with the pixels above and to the left of the middle wrapping around and appearing at the right and bottom ends of the image.

We can do this using the `ifftshift` function, applied to the kernel after padding. When padding the kernel, we need to take care that the origin (middle of the kernel) is at location `k_im.shape // 2` (integer division), within the kernel image `k_im`. Initially the origin is at `[3,3]//2 == [1,1]`. Usually, the image whose size we're matching is even in size, for example `[256,256]`. The origin there will be at `[256,256]//2 == [128,128]`. This means that we need to pad a different amount to the left and to the right (and bottom and top). We need to be careful computing this padding:

```py
sz = img.shape  # the sizes we're matching
kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
sz = (sz[0] - kernel.shape[0], sz[1] - kernel.shape[1])  # total amount of padding
kernel = np.pad(kernel, (((sz[0]+1)//2, sz[0]//2), ((sz[1]+1)//2, sz[1]//2)), 'constant')
kernel = fftpack.ifftshift(kernel)
```

Note that the input image, `img`, does not need to be padded (though you can do this if you want to enforce a size for which the FFT is cheaper). There is also no need to apply `fftshift` to the result of the FFT before multiplication, and then reverse this shift right after, these shifts are redundant. You should use `fftshift` only if you want to display the Fourier domain image. Finally, applying logarithmic scaling to the filtered image is wrong.

The resulting code is (I'm using pyplot for display, not using PIL at all):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = misc.face()[:,:,0]

kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
sz = (img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0], img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1])  # total amount of padding
kernel = np.pad(kernel, (((sz[0]+1)//2, sz[0]//2), ((sz[1]+1)//2, sz[1]//2)), 'constant')
kernel = fftpack.ifftshift(kernel)

filtered = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.fft2(img) * fftpack.fft2(kernel)))
plt.imshow(filtered, vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

Note that I am taking the real part of the inverse FFT. The imaginary part should contain only values very close to zero, which are the result of rounding errors in the computations. Taking the absolute value, though common, is incorrect. For example, you might want to apply a filter to an image that contains negative values, or apply a filter that produces negative values. Taking the absolute value here would create artefacts. If the output of the inverse FFT contains imaginary values significantly different from zero, then there is an error in the way that the filtering kernel was padded.

Also note that the kernel here is tiny, and consequently the blurring effect is tiny too. To better see the effect of the blurring, make a larger kernel, for example `np.ones((7,7)) / 49`.

Comment: This is perfect, would this work for all kind of kernels in general, say Sobel kernel or any kernel for that matter ?

Comment: @ShivamThakur: Yes, it would. One thing I forgot to say here: Convolutions through the FFT are only efficient for larger kernels. For a small kernel such as the 3x3 kernel here or a Sobel kernel, you are better off not using the FFT at all.

Comment: I did it Sobel and other 3x3 kernels, it seems I getting the prefect result intended, I’m doing the convolution in Fourier domain to speed up processing speed basically.

Comment: @ShivamThakur: As I said, for Sobel or other 3x3 kernels, this is very inefficient. Just use something like `scipy.signal.convolve2d` instead. Time your code, don’t implement convolution this way assuming it is faster!

Comment: I am not allowed to use any libraries except for scipys fft, also do we have to flip the kernel horizontally and vertically before convolving ?

Comment: @ShivamThakur: No, you shouldn't flip the kernel. Unless you want to compute the correlation instead of the convolution. Do generate the Sobel kernels correctly though, I've seen them written down flipped (so that they can be used with a correlation function, as e.g. OpenCV does). Sobel should have [1,0,-1], not [-1,0,1].

Comment: I have added a new question regarding your code implementation, could you look into it