# Convolving sobel operator in x direction in frequency domain

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft, convolution

I implemented the code [given by Cris Luengo for convolution in frequency in domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977551/7328782), however I'm not getting the intended gradient image in x direction.

Image without flipping the kernel in x and y direction:

[image: Image with normal kernel]

Image after flipping the kernel:

[image]

If you notice, the second image is same as given by `ImageKernel` filter from the pillow library. Also, one thing to notice is I don't have to flip the kernel if I apply Sobel kernel in y direction, I get the exactly intended image.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageOps,ImageFilter
from pylab import figure, title, imshow, hist, grid,show

im1=Image.open("astronaut.png").convert('L') 
# im1=ImageOps.grayscale(im1)
img=np.array(im1)

# kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
# kernel=np.array([[0,-1,0],[-1,4,-1],[0,-1,0]])
kernel=np.array([[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]])
kernel=np.rot90(kernel,2)
print(kernel)

sz = (img.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0], img.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1])  # total 
amount of padding
kernel = np.pad(kernel, (((sz[0]+1)//2, sz[0]//2), ((sz[1]+1)//2, sz[1]//2)), 
'constant')

kernel = fftpack.ifftshift(kernel)

filtered = np.real(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.fft2(img) * 
fftpack.fft2(kernel)))+np.imag(fftpack.ifft2(fftpack.fft2(img) * 
fftpack.fft2(kernel)))
filtered=np.maximum(0,np.minimum(filtered,255))
im2=Image.open("astronaut.png").convert('L')

u=im2.filter(ImageFilter.Kernel((3,3), [-1,0,1,-2,0,2,-1,0,1], 
scale=1, offset=0))

fig2=figure()

ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(221)  
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig2.add_subplot(223)

ax1.title.set_text('Original Image')
ax2.title.set_text('After convolving in freq domain')
ax3.title.set_text('imagefilter conv')
ax1.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(filtered,cmap='gray')
ax3.imshow(np.array(u),cmap='gray')

show()
```

Comment: `kernel=np.array([[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]])` is the flipped kernel, you need to do `kernel=np.array([[1,0,-1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])`. And to get the kernel for the y-axis, use `np.swapaxes` or `np.transpose`, not `rot90` (which additionally flips the kernel).

Comment: would I also have to transpose the image array(img=np.array(im1) since it gives image data in transposed dimensions?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I'm confused as to how my kernel array is already a flipped kernel, isnt it [-1 0 1][-2 0 2][-1 0 1] itself or the numpy representation flips, because when I send the same values to Imagefilter.kernel the images obtained should be similar even if the kernel values in themsevles are wrong

Comment: No, to compute a derivative you need to convolve with `[1,0,-1]`. This is given wrong in lots of places, mainly because some popular libraries implement a correlation function, not a convolution function, and so you need to use a flipped kernel to get it right.

Comment: It seems I got the answer from this link [link](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3134) , imagekernel implementation of asymmetric kernels is wrong in the pillow library

Comment: Yep, you found a bug! :) -- Also, it looks like how they want to fix it is by implementing correlation, not convolution. Libraries like this is why the Sobel kernel is taught wrongly in so many places!

Comment: You cleared up a plethora of things!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `np.fft` module's FFT implementation too and here is how we can obtain convolution with sobel horizontal kernel in frequency domain (by the convolution theorem):

```
h, w = im.shape
kernel = np.array(array([[-1,  0,  1],
       [-2,  0,  2],
       [-1,  0,  1]])) #sobel_filter_x
k = len(kernel) // 2 # assuming odd-length square kernel, here it's 3x3
kernel_padded = np.pad(kernel, [(h//2-k-1, h//2-k), (w//2-k-1, w//2-k)]) 
im_freq = np.fft.fft2(im)                  # input image frequency
kernel_freq = np.fft.fft2(kernel_padded)   # kernel frequency 
out_freq = im_freq * kernel_freq           # frequency domain convolution output
out = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft2(out_freq)).real # spatial domain output
```

The below figure shows the input, kernel and output images in spatial and frequency domain:

[image]

Comment: Note that the output of Sobel is supposed to have negative values also, the way it's displayed here misses all the negative values. The `ifftshift` operation should be applied to the padded kernel before calling `fft2`; the results are, I believe, the same, but it is confusing the way it's implemented here. Finally, Sobel is defined flipped here, suitable to be applied as a correlation, not as a convolution; for convolution, you'd have positive values on the left size, and negative ones on the right.