# How to compute the derivative of a function through the Fourier domain?

Tags: math, image-processing, fft, convolution, derivative

I am currently working on a project where I have to reconstruct an Image from its gradient by solving a Poisson equation, which we solve in the Fourier domain.

The solution involves the product of the image's FT and that of the discrete derivation filter. In the Fourier domain, this is defined as the coordinate-wise product of the two.

I understand how the FT of an image is computed, however I have trouble understanding how I should compute that of a filter, as `[0 -1 1]` for horizontal differences. Should I use the same formula as for images? This seems weird to me as I would keep only 2 components of my FT after having multiplied it with the image's FT.

Comment: I edited your question a bit, please revert my changes or [edit] further if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the convolution though the Fourier domain, one first pads the kernel with zeros to have the same size as the image, then computes the FFT of both the image and the padded kernel, and then multiplies those two frequency spectra. It is important that the origin of the kernel be put in the right place when padding. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877892/convolving-image-with-kernel-in-fourier-domain/54977551#54977551) for details on how to do the padding right.

However, to compute derivatives you do not want to do it this way. Instead, use the [Fourier property](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html) that the derivative in the spatial domain is a multiplication with *jω*.

The `[1,0,-1]` filter (or `[0,1,-1]` or whichever you want to use) is a discrete **approximation** to the derivative. If you go through the Fourier domain, you might as well compute the **exact** derivative.

For example, in MATLAB you would do:

```matlab
a = imread('cameraman.tif');
A = fft2(a);
N = size(A,2); % we're computing the x-derivative here, that is dimension 2 in MATLAB
w = ifftshift((0:N-1)-floor(N/2)) * (pi / N);
B = A .* (1i * w); % for MATLAB R2016a and older, use bsxfun here
b = real(ifft2(B));
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand for the padding, but I am not sure how I would use the exact derivative in my case. I am using the solution explained in this  [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/screenedPoissonEq.pdf) (eq. 29), where they divide by the Operator's FT

Comment: @bathal: Under section 4 it is already using the solution I suggested here. *i* 2π *s* is the same as *jω* (*s* goes from -0.5 to 0.5, *ω* goes from -π to π). *s*<sup>x</sup> is the x-coordinate frequency, *s*<sup>y</sup> is the y-coordinate frequency.