# Inconsistency when comparing scipy, torch and fourier periodic convolution

Tags: python, scipy, fft, pytorch, convolution

I'm implementing a 2d periodic convolution on a synthetic image in three different ways: using `scipy`, using `torch` and using the `Fourier` transform (also under `torch` framework).

However, I've got different results. Performing the operation by hand I can see that `scipy`'s convolution yields the correct results. `torch`'s spatial version, on the other hand, yields the expected result inverted. Finally, the `Fourier` version returns something unexpected.

The code is the following:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import torch.nn.functional as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def numpy_periodic_conv(f, k):
    H, W = f.shape
    periodic_f = np.hstack([f, f])
    periodic_f = np.vstack([periodic_f, periodic_f])
    conv = sig.convolve2d(periodic_f, k, mode='same')
    conv = conv[H // 2:-H // 2, W // 2:-W // 2]
    return periodic_f, conv

def torch_periodic_conv(f, k):
    H, W = f.shape[-2:]
    periodic_f = f.repeat(1, 1, 2, 2)
    conv = F.conv2d(periodic_f, k, padding=1)
    conv = conv[:, :, H // 2:-H // 2, W // 2:-W // 2]
    return periodic_f.squeeze().numpy(), conv.squeeze().numpy()

def torch_fourier_conv(f, k):
    pad_x = f.shape[-2] - k.shape[-2]
    pad_y = f.shape[-1] - k.shape[-1]
    expanded_kernel = F.pad(k, [0, pad_x, 0, pad_y])
    fft_x = torch.rfft(f, 2, onesided=False)
    fft_kernel = torch.rfft(expanded_kernel, 2, onesided=False)
    real = fft_x[:, :, :, :, 0] * fft_kernel[:, :, :, :, 0] - \
           fft_x[:, :, :, :, 1] * fft_kernel[:, :, :, :, 1]
    im = fft_x[:, :, :, :, 0] * fft_kernel[:, :, :, :, 1] + \
         fft_x[:, :, :, :, 1] * fft_kernel[:, :, :, :, 0]
    fft_conv = torch.stack([real, im], -1) # (a+bj)*(c+dj) = (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)j
    ifft_conv = torch.irfft(fft_conv, 2, onesided=False)
    return expanded_kernel.squeeze().numpy(), ifft_conv.squeeze().numpy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = np.concatenate([np.ones((10, 5)), np.zeros((10, 5))], 1)
    k = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])

    f_tensor = torch.from_numpy(f).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).float()
    k_tensor = torch.from_numpy(k).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).float()

    np_periodic_f, np_periodic_conv = numpy_periodic_conv(f, k)
    tc_periodic_f, tc_periodic_conv = torch_periodic_conv(f_tensor, k_tensor)
    tc_fourier_k, tc_fourier_conv = torch_fourier_conv(f_tensor, k_tensor)

    print('Spatial numpy conv shape= ', np_periodic_conv.shape)
    print('Spatial torch conv shape= ', tc_periodic_conv.shape)
    print('Fourier torch conv shape= ', tc_fourier_conv.shape)

    r_np = dict(name='numpy', im=np_periodic_f, k=k, conv=np_periodic_conv)
    r_torch = dict(name='torch', im=tc_periodic_f, k=k, conv=tc_periodic_conv)
    r_fourier = dict(name='fourier', im=f, k=tc_fourier_k, conv=tc_fourier_conv)
    titles = ['{} im', '{} kernel', '{} conv']
    results = [r_np, r_torch, r_fourier]
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
    for i, r_dict in enumerate(results):
        axs[i, 0].imshow(r_dict['im'], cmap='gray')
        axs[i, 0].set_title(titles[0].format(r_dict['name']))
        axs[i, 1].imshow(r_dict['k'], cmap='gray')
        axs[i, 1].set_title(titles[1].format(r_dict['name']))
        axs[i, 2].imshow(r_dict['conv'], cmap='gray')
        axs[i, 2].set_title(titles[2].format(r_dict['name']))
    plt.show()
```

The results I'm obtaining:

*Note: The image for both `numpy`and `torch` versions show the periodic image, which is required to perform the periodic convolution. The kernel for the `Fourier` version shows the original kernel zero-padded to the image size, which is required to compute the element-wise multiplication in the frequency domain.*

-Edit1: There was an error when in the multiplication in the `Fourier` version, I was doing `(ac-bd)+(ad-bc)j` instead of `(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)j`. But now, I get the convolution shifted by one column.

[image: results]

-Edit2: `torch`'s spatial convolution results is inverted because the operation is actually a cross-correlation. This was confirmed in the `pytorch`'s official forum [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/different-convolution-results-using-spatial-and-frequency-convolution/40039/2?u=arc144). Furthermore, after fixing the kernel padding as `Cris Luengo`'s answer, the frequency method yielded the same results as the correlations. This is rather strange for me because, as far as I know, the frequency property hold for convolution, not correlation.

New-results after fixing the kernel:

[image: new_results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The FFT result is wrong because the padding is wrong. When padding, you need to put the origin (center of the kernel) at the top-left corner of the image. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877892/convolving-image-with-kernel-in-fourier-domain/54977551#54977551) for details.
2. The difference between the other two is the difference between a convolution and a correlation. It looks like the “numpy“ result is a convolution, the “torch” one a correlation.

Comment: Actually, is the other way around. It seems `pytorch`'s convolution is actually a correlation (I've also received a offical response in the `pytorch`'s forum confirming that). But now it is weird because the frequency method is yielding the same results as the correlation.

Comment: @Eduardo: Oh, you’re showing the middle part of the output, not the left half as I first thought. The x-axis tick labels confused me there. In that case, yes, the first result is convolution.

Comment: @Eduardo: If your FFT method yields the reverse, you either have a wrong sign, wrong padding, or wrong cropping. I recommend that you repeat your experiment without cropping, and with an image that is not ambiguous like this one. For example make one bar wider than the other, or use a delta pulse as input (a single pixel with value 1, the convolution output will be identical to the kernel).