# Why image is shifted when using ifft2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, convolution

I'm implementing 2-D convolution by using FFT. Here is my code:

```
img = im2single(imread('dog.bmp'));
filter = fspecial('gaussian', 53, 3);
F = fft2(img);
mask = fft2(filter, size(img, 1), size(img, 2));
filtered_img = ifft2(F .* mask);
imshow(real(filtered_img));
```

Here is the original image:

[image]

The result is here:
[image]

Why does this happen? How can I fix it? Please help me.
Many thanks.

Comment: Same question but with Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54877892/convolving-image-with-kernel-in-fourier-domain/54977551

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the frequency response of your filter,

> `filter = fspecial('gaussian', 53, 3);`

is **shifted** with respect to the origin of coordinates. To check this, use

```
imagesc(filter)
```

[image]

You can see that `filter` has its maximum at coordinates `27`,`27`, not `1`,`1`. The amount of shift can be computed (for odd-sized impulse response) as `(size(filter)-1)/2`, which in this case gives `[26, 26]`.

In the following, I'll use this image as an example:

```
img = im2single(imread('cameraman.tif')); % size [256, 256]
```

---

Later in your code, when you call `fft2` with the optional second and third arguments,

> `mask = fft2(filter, size(img, 1), size(img, 2));`

the first input is implicitly right-**padded** with zeros in each dimension to match the specified size, which is `256` for my example `img` . You can check this by plotting its inverse transform:

```
imagesc(real(ifft2(mask)))
```

[image]

---

After that, your code multiplies the transforms of the original image and the impulse response of the filter, and then transforms back. That's equivalent to a **circular convolution** of the original image `img` and the impulse response `filter`. Now, since the latter is shifted by `26` samples with respect to the origin in both dimensions, that produces a **circular shift** in the output signal. **This** is the problem you observe.

---

To solve this, you need to correct for the shifting, while taking into account the padding.

The simplest way is to manually do the padding (instead of letting `fft2` do it implicitly) and at the same time circularly shift `(size(filter)-1)/2` samples to the left in each dimension:

```
filter_corrected = filter; % initiallize
filter_corrected(size(img, 1), size(img, 2)) = 0; % this right-pads with zeros
shift = (size(filter)-1)/2; % as seen above
filter_corrected = filter_corrected( ...
    mod((1:end)+shift(1)-1, end)+1, ...
    mod((1:end)+shift(2)-1, end)+1); % this undoes the circular shifting
```

Now the corrected impulse response, `filter_corrected`, has the required size and its maximum is at `1`, `1` (although it's hard to observe in the example):

```
imagesc(filter_corrected)
```

[image]

So you can use `filter_corrected` in the rest of your code:

```
F = fft2(img);
mask = fft2(filter_corrected, size(img, 1), size(img, 2));
filtered_img = ifft2(F .* mask);
imshow(real(filtered_img));
```

With this, the original and filtered images are

```
imshow(img)
figure
imshow(real(filtered_img))
```

[image]

[image]

---

As **additional notes**,

- Observe how the filtering process causes a little bit of the lower part of the image (legs of the cameraman) to "spill" into the upper part. This is a consequence of the method you use for filtering, namely multiplying in the DFT domain, which corresponds to **circular** convolution in the original domain.
- It's better not to use `filter` as a variable name, because that shadows the built-in function with the same name.

Comment: thank you for the great answer. But I have a question about this sentence you wrote: "You can see that filter has its maximum at coordinates 27,27, not 1,1". Why the maximum value would be at (1,1). I thought that when creating a gaussian filter (odd-size (h, w)), the maximum value will be at ((h+1)/2, (w+1)/2)) coordinate. Then I can calculate convolution operation. Am I right?

Comment: When you create a filter of size 53×53 the maximum is at the center, that is, 27,27. But then, when you convolve you are introducing a shift of 27−1 = 26 pixels into the image. To correct that, you need to shift the impulse respose of the filter so that its center is at 1,1. Since we are talking about _circular_ convolution, the required shift is circular too