# Restoring colored image via inverse filtration

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, fft

My task is to implement an inverse filtering algorithm that comprises following steps:

1. Convolving image function with a distortion function f1
2. Get the Fourier spectrum of the resultant function f1
3. Get the Fourier spectrum of the distortion function f2
4. Perform the inverse Fourier  transform on the result of the division of function f1 and f2

Algorithms' implementation on Python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft2, ifft2

img = cv2.imread("beato.jpg")
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 3), 0)
gaussian_kernel = cv2.getGaussianKernel(3, 1)

dst_fft = fft2(dst)
gaussian_kernel_fft = fft2(gaussian_kernel)

img_corrected_fft = dst_fft/gaussian_kernel_fft
img_corrected = ifftn(img_corrected_fft)
cv2.imshow("img_corrected", img_corrected)
```

As far as I see, `dst_fft` and `gaussian_kernel_fft` can't be divided as they have different shapes, however the convolution of `cv2.GaussianBlur` with the original image works just perfect. My guess is that each of the distorted image channels should be divided by `gaussian_kernel_fft` and then `ifft`'ed. However, I don't have even the slightest clue how to do this properly.

Comment: The dimensionality problem is because `img` is an RGB image (or rather, BGR, OpenCV does things the wrong way around). Use `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` as a 2nd argument to `cv2.imread()`. But then you'll have another problem, because `gaussian_kernel` is not the same size as `img`. You need  to pad it with zeros before applying the FFT. And you also need to take care that the origin of the kernel is in the top-left pixel, which you do with `ifftshift`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977551/7328782

Comment: 1. You mean that the result of the algorithm is no different from the result of a gray image? 2. Does padding with zeros literally mean that the 'gaussian_kernel' should be the size of a 'dst' and filled with zeros except first three digits? 3. You mean that convolution starts from the top-left pixes? Why should 'ifftshift' be applied?

Comment: 1: It is more difficult to work with color images. Start with a gray-scale image, if you get it to work correctly, then you can try to do the same with a color image. 2: Yes, the two images you multiply in the Fourier domain must be of the same size, and you accomplish that by making them the same size before applying the FFT. See the answer I linked above. 3:  The origin of the FFT is the top-left pixel, it has nothing to do with convolution. If the output of the IFFT is not real-valued (the imaginary component is 0 within rounding errors), then you messed up the origin.

Comment: Guess I got it, but as a result I get white image. The final version of the code: https://pastebin.com/jaCVd7a3