# How to select an appropriate Sobel kernel for FFT 2D?

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm using FFT 2D to create a Sobel image. It's working great! But one issue is that there are two lines in the top and in the left that are duplicated. That's becase of the sobel kernels `K_y` and `K_x`. They are not centred in the `fft2` algorithm and that's the reason why I'm getting a such border at the left and the top.

If the `K_y` and `K_x` was completly centered in `m/2` and `n/2`, then I will get four duplicated images. So I must center the sobel kernels in `(0,0)`, but I'm already doing that.

```
  % Get X
  X = imread('image.png');

  % Gray scaled image
  if(size(X, 3) > 1)
    X = rgb2gray(X);
  end

  % Create kernels for X-direction and Y-direction
  K_x = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];
  K_y = [-1 -2 -1; 0 0 0; 1 2 1];

  % Do conv2 with FFT
  Gx = conv2_fft(X, K_x);
  Gy = conv2_fft(X, K_y);

  % Compute the gradients
  G = sqrt(Gx.^2 + Gy.^2);

  % Compute the orientations
  O = atan2d(Gy, Gx);

end

function G = conv2_fft(X, K)
  % Create kernel
  [m, n] = size(X);
  kernel = zeros(m, n);
  [m, n] = size(K);
  kernel(1:m, 1:n) = K;

  % Do FFT2 on X and kernel
  A = fft2(X);
  B = fft2(kernel);

  % Compute the convolutional matrix - abs to remove zero imaginary numbers
  G = abs(ifft2(A.*B));
end
```

[image]

**Question:**

How to I center the Sobel kernels by selecting the appropriate kernel?

Comment: This answer explains how to pad the kernel for convolution in FFT. Example code is Python, but the logic is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977551/7328782

Comment: Note that for a small kernel like Sobel, using the FFT to compute convolution is not at all efficient. You’re better off using `conv2`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `conv2` is using FFT2 =)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for that URL link. I will read that.

Comment: No, `conv2` does not use FFT, it implements “direct convolution”. That means, it implements the plain old convolution sum directly.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I prefer to use FFT2 because it's very optimized. I'm also using FFTPack with 2D. So that's the reason why I prefer FFT2. By the way! It works. Se my answer.

Comment: I don’t understand your “very optimized” claim. Convolutions through the FFT are only more efficient for very large kernels. Convolution with a small 3x3 kernel is at least an order of magnitude faster as a direct convolution compared to an FFT convolution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo In theory...yes. But apply this with assembly code or C code, then FFT is much more optimized than three of more for-loops for doing convolutional multiplication onto a huge matrix.

Comment: No. Please don’t make assumptions about optimizations and computational cost. Our intuition fails with that way too often (this is true even for very experienced programmers). Implement the operations, time them, then decide which is faster. I have done this, I have the experience to say what I’m saying. You don’t need to take my word for it, but you should definitely not assume you’re right without doing the experiment first.

Comment: Just computing a single 2D FFT is significantly more expensive than applying a 3x3 convolution. You are using 3 of them!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Only in theory. When you are writing fast optimized `C` code, then iterations are the rooth of evil. Having e.g 4 for-loops that doing 3x3 convolution onto a e.g. 500x500 matrix, takes more time that doing FFT2D onto a kernel, that mutliplies with a matrix. Belive me, I have tried.

Comment: @CrisLuengo https://github.com/marton78/pffft

Comment: So you think the FFT doesn’t use loops???

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes it does, but it's more optimized. Having 4 small for loops is much slower than 1 big for-loop.

Comment: You need to stop this magical thinking. "small loops slower than big loop". The FFT is expensive. I just did this experiment in MATLAB: `X = randn(1024, 1024); K = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]; timeit(@()conv2(X, K)), timeit(@()fft2(X))`. I suggest you copy-paste that into your MATLAB to verify what I'm saying. For me it shows that `conv2` takes 0.0010s, and `fft2` takes 0.0033s, 3.3 times as much! Your `conv2_fft` does three FFTs, so takes at least 0.010s (I timed it, it takes 0.0132 s, which is the 3xFFT plus the multiplication; this is 10x as long as the direct convolution of `conv2`).

Comment: As I said, we're (as humans) really bad at guessing what code will be faster. We **must** time it to know. Unless you actually do these experiments, you'll be stabbing in the dark, and often picking the wrong algorithm or the wrong bit of code.

Comment: @Cris Luengo MATLAB fft2 is composed from linear fft-s and can realize 2D-convolution, so conv2_fft is expected to have smaller symptotic effort for convolution with common patterns. In case of the local Sobel filter a linear pipeline can serve with effort O(n), certainly faster pre-asymptotical and asmyptotical than all fft approaches

Comment: @SamGinrich I’m sorry, I have no idea what any of that means.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Just as Cris Luengo said. The kernel must be shifted.

```
function G = conv2_fft(X, K)
  % Create kernel
  [m, n] = size(X);
  kernel = zeros(m, n);
  [m, n] = size(K);
  kernel(1:m-1, 1:n-1) = K(2:3, 2:3);
  kernel(end, 1:n-1) = K(1, 2:3);
  kernel(1:m-1, end) = K(2:3, 1);
  kernel(end, end) = K(1,1);

  % Do FFT2 on X and kernel
  A = fft2(X);
  B = fft2(kernel);

  % Compute the convolutional matrix - abs to remove zero imaginary numbers
  G = abs(ifft2(A.*B));
end
```

Result:

[image]