# Replicating SciPy's convolve function with FFT

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, fft, convolution

I am trying to replicate the `scipy.ndimage.convolve()` functionality with convolution theorem using FFTs. Here is my code so far:

```
# Center kernel
kernel = np.fft.fftshift(kernel)

# Determine padding size 
pad_size = [(k, k) for k in kernel.shape]

# Pad the image
padded_image = np.pad(image, pad_size, mode='edge')

# Compute the FFT of the padded image and the kernel
image_fft = np.fft.fft2(padded_image)
kernel_fft = np.fft.fft2(kernel, s=padded_image.shape)

# Multiply the FFTs
convolution_fft = image_fft * kernel_fft

# Compute the inverse FFT to get the convolution result
convolution = np.fft.ifft2(convolution_fft)

# Crop the convolution result back to original size
cropped_convolution = convolution[pad_size[0][0]:-pad_size[0][1], pad_size[1][0]:-pad_size[1][1]]

return np.real(cropped_convolution)
```

When I test it with this testing code:

```
kernel = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
kernel = kernel / kernel.sum()  # normalise kernel

filtered = fft_convolution(image_crop, kernel)

import scipy.signal

reference = scipy.ndimage.convolve(image_crop, kernel, mode='nearest')

ssd = np.sum(np.power(filtered - reference, 2))

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1); plt.title('Fast convolution');            plt.imshow(filtered,  cmap='gray', vmin=0,  vmax=1)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2); plt.title('Reference result');            plt.imshow(reference, cmap='gray', vmin=0,  vmax=1)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3); plt.title(f'Difference (SSD={ssd:.3f})'); plt.imshow(filtered - reference,   vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```

I get a difference of SSD=17.157 which looks like this:
[image]

Images look identical to me but it looks like I am doing something wrong here. What is  it I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should pad the kernel first, equally on all sides, then apply `fftshift`. Here I explained it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977551/7328782