# Is there a bug in ftConv function for computing convolution using FFT?

Tags: c++, fft, convolution

I am writing the code for implementing a convolution theorem to compute convolution using Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). As for now, my implementation consists of 4 main functions:

1. `Conv` is just a regular convolution;
2. `fft2d` is responsible for computing 2D FFT of an image;
3. `ifft2d` computes inverse Fourier transform (here I should mention that direct application of `fft2d` and then `ifft2d` (e.g. `ifft2d<int>(fft2d<int>(image))` gives the same results;
4. `ftConv` is a FFT-using convolution. Here I zero-pad either image or kernel to the size of biggest of these 2, compute FFT of both of them, and then multiply them element-wise. After that, I perform `ifft2d` on the result.

The thing is that I get completely different result compared to my default convolution. For instance, consider the following code:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> image = {{1, 2, 0, 4, 5},
                                           {6, 0, 8, 0, 10},
                                           {0, 12, 13, 14, 0},
                                           {16, 0, 18, 0, 20},
                                           {21, 22, 0, 24, 25}};
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> kernel = {{-1, 0, 1},
                                            {-2, 0, 2},
                                            {-1, 0, 1}};

    auto result1 = Conv(image, kernel);
    auto result2 = ftConv(image, kernel);

    for (const auto& row : result1) {
        for (auto pixel : row)
            std::cout << (double) pixel << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (const auto& row : result2) {
        for (auto pixel : row)
            std::cout << (double) pixel << " ";

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 16 4 -4 0
0 30 4 -22 0
0 -4 4 16 0
0 0 0 0 0

-15 -15 31 4 -4 
-57 -7 29 41 -6 
-37 2 19 21 -6 
3 4 11 -15 -4 
21 5 6 -29 -4
```

Here's the code of 4 functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <chrono>

#define freqMat std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>>
#define freqVec std::vector<std::complex<double>>
#define cmplx std::complex<double>

template <class T, class U>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> Conv(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& image, const std::vector<std::vector<U>>& kernel) {
    size_t imgHeight = image.size();
    size_t imgWidth = image[0].size();
    int kSize = kernel.size();
    int kCenter = kSize / 2;

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result(imgHeight, std::vector<T>(imgWidth, 0));

    for (int i = kCenter; i < imgHeight - kCenter; ++i) {
        for (int j = kCenter; j < imgWidth - kCenter; ++j) {
            T sum = 0;

            for (int k = -kCenter; k <= kCenter; ++k)
                for (int l = -kCenter; l <= kCenter; ++l)
                    sum += image[i + k][j + l] * kernel[k + kCenter][l + kCenter];

            result[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <class T>
freqMat fft2d(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& image) {
    size_t imgHeight = image.size();
    size_t imgWidth = image[0].size();

    // Convert image to complex values
    freqMat imgTransformed(imgHeight, freqVec(imgWidth));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j)
            imgTransformed[i][j] = cmplx(image[i][j], 0);

    // Apply fft2d to each row
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
        freqVec row = imgTransformed[i];
        freqVec transformedRow(imgWidth);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j) {
            cmplx sum(0, 0);
            for (size_t k = 0; k < imgWidth; ++k)
                sum += row[k] * std::exp(cmplx(0, -2 * M_PI * j * k / imgWidth));

            transformedRow[j] = sum;
        }

        imgTransformed[i] = transformedRow;
    }

    // Apply fft2d to each column
    for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j) {
        freqVec column(imgHeight);
        freqVec transformedColumn(imgHeight);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
            column[i] = imgTransformed[i][j];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
            cmplx sum(0, 0);
            for (size_t k = 0; k < imgHeight; ++k)
                sum += column[k] * std::exp(cmplx(0, -2 * M_PI * i * k / imgHeight));

            transformedColumn[i] = sum;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
            imgTransformed[i][j] = transformedColumn[i];
    }

    return imgTransformed;
}


template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> ifft2d(const freqMat& image) {
    size_t imgHeight = image.size();
    size_t imgWidth = image[0].size();

    freqMat imgITransformed(imgHeight, freqVec(imgWidth));
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result(imgHeight, std::vector<T>(imgWidth));

    // Apply ifft2d to each column
    for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j) {
        freqVec column(imgHeight);
        freqVec columnITransformed(imgHeight);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
            column[i] = image[i][j];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
            cmplx sum(0, 0);
            for (size_t k = 0; k < imgHeight; ++k)
                sum += column[k] * std::exp(cmplx(0, 2 * M_PI * i * k / imgHeight));

            columnITransformed[i] = sum / (double) imgHeight;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
            imgITransformed[i][j] = columnITransformed[i];
    }

    // Apply ifft2d to each row
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
        freqVec row = imgITransformed[i];
        freqVec rowITransformed(imgWidth);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j) {
            cmplx sum(0, 0);
            for (size_t k = 0; k < imgWidth; ++k)
                sum += row[k] * std::exp(cmplx(0, 2 * M_PI * j * k / imgWidth));

            rowITransformed[j] = sum / (double) imgWidth;
        }

        imgITransformed[i] = rowITransformed;
    }

    // Convert the values to real
    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgWidth; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < imgHeight; ++j)
            result[i][j] = static_cast<T>(std::real(imgITransformed[i][j]));

    return result;
}

template <class T, class U>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> ftConv(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& image, const std::vector<std::vector<U>>& kernel) {
    size_t imgHeight = image.size(), imgWidth = image[0].size();
    size_t kWidth = kernel.size(), kHeight = kernel[0].size();

    size_t resWidth = std::max(imgWidth, kWidth);
    size_t resHeight = std::max(imgHeight, kHeight);

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> imgPadded(resHeight, std::vector<T>(resWidth, 0));
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> kPadded(resHeight, std::vector<T>(resWidth, 0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < imgWidth; ++j)
            imgPadded[i + (resHeight - imgHeight) / 2][j + (resWidth - imgWidth) / 2] = image[i][j];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < kHeight; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < kWidth; ++j)
            kPadded[i + (resHeight - kHeight) / 2][j + (resWidth - kWidth) / 2] = kernel[i][j];

    freqMat imgTransformed = fft2d<T>(imgPadded);
    freqMat kTransformed = fft2d<U>(kPadded);
    freqMat resultTransformed(resHeight, freqVec(resWidth));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < resHeight; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < resWidth; ++j)
            resultTransformed[i][j] = imgTransformed[i][j] * kTransformed[i][j];

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result = ifft2d<T>(resultTransformed);

    return result;
}
```

What makes `ftConv` function produce wrong results and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you thing the result is wrong? What result do you expect?

Comment: @273K I expect the same result as produced by `Conv` function.

Comment: Most likely you are not padding the kernel right. And since you discard the imaginary component of the result, you can’t even tell if something is going wrong. You should at least assert that the imaginary component is approximately zero. See here for how to pad the kernel:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54977551/7328782

Comment: Also, your FFT function is not an FFT, it computes the DFT sum directly.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to diagnose if the test image was sparse with one or two spikes say 100, 10 in a background of zeroes and the kernel had more distinct values and a peak in the middle. Then we might be able to figure out where the mistake lies. Since you are doing discrete DFT rather than FFT you don't really need to zero pad you just have to remember that there are implicit periodic boundary conditions at the edges. Zero padding the image by enough to prevent your kernel from overlapping edge data should be sufficient to prevent surprises.