# Averaging over array neighbour values

Tags: python, arrays, list

Given an array of [x,y] as follows, I'd like to return a new array with the average of the 3x3 sub-arrays. E.g. the following array:

```
image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]
```

Should return

```
new_image = [[5, 4],
            [4, 4]]
```

I've managed to get this far at which point I can get the new array as a list of the form:

```
new_image = [5,4,4,4]
```

This is my approach:

```
h = list(range(1,len(image)-1))
w = list(range(1,len(image[0])-1))

def square_sum(image,i,j):
    sum = image[i-1][j-1] + image[i-1][j] + image[i][j-1] + image[i+1][j] + image[i][j+1] + image[i+1][j+1] + image[i][j] + image[i-1][j+1] + image[i+1][j-1] 
    return sum//9

new_image = []

for i in h:
    for j in w:
        new_image.append(square_sum(image,i,j))
return(new_image)
```

So my question is how can I get my output to be an array of arrays instead of just a list. (I've realised it's a lot easier to do this with Numpy but would like to see how I could go about solving it in line with the above).

Comment: I don't understand how any of these values average to 5 or 4

Comment: @NicolasGervais I've edited the question to explain - it's the 3x3 averages.

Comment: Hi, as in the average of the 3x3 sub arrays surrounding each element in the original array. E.g. take [1,1] = 6  in the original array. The sum of the 3x3 sub array with 6 as the centre is 47. Therefore, average is 5.

Comment: This might be relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086557/convolve2d-just-by-using-numpy (using 3x3 convolving filter where every value is 1/9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must manually create both the outer *and inner* lists:

```
new_image = []

for i in h:
    new_image.append([])  # at each height, add a new inner list
    for j in w:
        new_image[-1].append(square_sum(image,i,j))
        #         ^ append to the last create inner list
```

Patterns of the form `for ... in ...: some_list.append(...)` usually are suitable to being written as a list comprehension. Both layers can be expressed at once by a nested comprehension:

```
 #           v outer layer                                 v
 new_image = [[square_sum(image,i,j) for j in w] for i in h]
 #            ^ inner layer                    ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the final loop with a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```
new_image = [[square_sum(image,i,j) for j in w] for i in h]
```

In your example, it returns:

```
[[5, 4], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we know number of elements in each row we can keep appending row wise rather than element wise to `new_image`. Code below:

```
image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]

h = list(range(1,len(image)-1))
w = list(range(1,len(image[0])-1))

def square_sum(image,i,j):
    sum = image[i-1][j-1] + image[i-1][j] + image[i][j-1] + image[i+1][j] + image[i][j+1] + image[i+1][j+1] + image[i][j] + image[i-1][j+1] + image[i+1][j-1] 
    return sum//9

new_image = []

for i in h:
    temp_row = []
    for j in w:
        temp_row.append(square_sum(image,i,j))
    new_image.append(temp_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use scipy, you can do a convolution with a 1/9 kernel:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d


image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]


kernel = np.ones([3,3]) / 9

convolve2d(image, kernel, mode='valid').astype(int)
```