# Enlarge holes in 2D array mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask, mathematical-morphology

I have a 2D binary mask and I want to enlarge the holes in it by creating squares of dimension WxW where W is a parameter.

Supposing W = 3 I would like to trasform this matrix:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Into this matrix:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I'm currently using numpy to manage arrays. I think I can do it but I can't find an efficient way to do it, and I'm not sure how to handle edge cases (if a 1 is in the upper right corner, I still want WxW squares, not smaller...)

Thanks to all.

Comment: I'd recommend you look up either opencv's morphological functions (they're easy to use and a mat is just an array) or look up how to run a convolutional function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can consider opencv, you can use [dilation](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
```

You can also consider [scipy's version](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html)

---

For pure numpy you will have to work a little by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43087507/913098) with a kernel of `ones`, and thresholding afterwards.