# How to erode an image only using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have the following M_Matrix

```
M = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

which I want to erose using this structuring element.

```
st_element = np.ones((3, 3))
```

The final output sould seem like this

```
Output = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

My question is: is it possible to do erosion using only numpy_functions ?
thanks

Comment: Why only numpy? You can perform a 2D convolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086557/convolve2d-just-by-using-numpy

Comment: It does seem a bit masochistic to try to do this without `scikit-image` or at least `scipy`. But really, you should do some research, then try some things, then come back with a question about aspects of the problem you can't crack. I'm not sure why a person would take the time to completely solve this for you when it's a 1-liner in `skimage`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sliding_window_view` (not the fastest, but not the slowest either)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

M = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]).astype(bool)

st_element = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=bool)

padded = np.pad(M, st_element.shape[0]//2)

windows = sliding_window_view(padded, window_shape=st_element.shape)

eroded = np.all(windows | ~st_element, axis=(-1, -2))
```

Checking that it gives the same as scipy:

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion
np.testing.assert_array_equal(eroded, binary_erosion(M, st_element))
```