# Optimize this Python function - apply a linear transformation based on parity of index

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I have this simple Python function:

```py
import numpy as np

def fast_transform(img, offset, factor):
    rep = (img.shape[0]//2, img.shape[1]//2)
    out = (img.astype(np.float32) - np.tile(offset, rep)) * np.tile(factor, rep)
    return out
```

The function gets an image (as a NXM numpy ndarray) and two 2x2 arrays (offset and factor). It then calculates a basic linear transformation on every pixel in the image based on it's parity in each dimension:
`out[i,j] = (out[i,j] - offset[i%2,j%2]) * factor[i%2,j%2]`

As you can see I used np.tile to try and speed up the function but this isn't fast enough for my needs (and I think the creation of the dummy np.tile arrays makes it sub-optimal). I tried to use numba but it doesn't support np.tile yet.

Can you help me optimize this function as much as possible? I am sure there is some simple way to do it I am missing.

Comment: Could this be rewritten as a set of 2d convolutions and then use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086557/convolve2d-just-by-using-numpy

Comment: As convolution aggregates values from neighbouring cells (and my transformation does not) I can't think of an obvious way to use this function

Comment: With numba, you don't need to use np.tile, you can just write the explicit for loops. For me, this is ~4x faster than the numpy function.

Comment: How big are `N`  and `M`? With a 10000x10000 array your numpy function finishes in less than 0.5s for me.

Comment: The arrays are not so big (approximately 1000x1000) but I need to run this function on a large set of them so every speed-up is important.


The explicit numba works quite well (on a test array I also got a x3-4 factor). You think it could be optimized more?

Comment: Well, you can [parallelise the for loops](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html) which is another ~30% faster for me with 1000x1000 arrays

Comment: Your conversion of img to float32 also probably doesn't do what you expect as unless `offset` and `factor` are float32, then the result will be float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use another library, you can use [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make your numpy function ~7x faster (though if your arrays have different shapes, this may not be ideal as JAX recompiles the function for different shapes):

```
from jax import config
config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

@jax.jit
def fast_transform_jax(img, offset, factor):
    rep = (img.shape[0]//2, img.shape[1]//2)
    out = (img.astype(np.float32) - jnp.tile(offset, rep)) * jnp.tile(factor, rep)
    return out
```

Slight modifications to the numba functions in @Andrej's answer so that they pass `allclose` with OPs function:

```
@nb.njit
def fast_transform_numba(img, offset, factor):
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    out = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = (img[i, j] - offset[i % 2, j % 2]) * factor[i % 2, j % 2]
    return out

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, offset, factor):
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    out = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(img.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = (img[i, j] - offset[i % 2, j % 2]) * factor[i % 2, j % 2]
    return out
```

Timings:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

N, M = 1000, 1000
img = rng.random((N, M)) * 50
offset = rng.random((2, 2)) * 40
factor = rng.random((2, 2)) * 30

assert np.allclose(fast_transform(img, offset, factor), fast_transform_numba(img, offset, factor))
assert np.allclose(fast_transform(img, offset, factor), fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, offset, factor))
assert np.allclose(fast_transform(img, offset, factor), fast_transform_jax(img, offset, factor))

%timeit fast_transform(img, offset, factor)
%timeit fast_transform_numba(img, offset, factor)
%timeit fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, offset, factor)
%timeit fast_transform_jax(img, offset, factor).block_until_ready()
```

Output:

```
3.59 ms ± 332 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.39 ms ± 37.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
871 µs ± 47.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
521 µs ± 36.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark! Never used `jax` before... does it have some advantages over `numba`/`cython`? +1

Comment: Wow it looks pretty cool!
I'll look into it - this seems like a really huge speed up... a shame numba doesn't support np.tile yet

Comment: @AndrejKesely I guess the main benefits are that you typically can write the same code you would in numpy and then jit it whereas numba and cython benefit from explicit loops. You can also run exactly the same code on GPUs.

Comment: @RyArazi I don't think numba having support for np.tile would be beneficial in this case as numba is typically faster with explicit for loops

Answer (score 1):

You can try naive approach using `numba`:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


@njit
def fast_transform_numba(img, offset, factor):
    out = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = (img[i, j] - offset[i % 2, j % 2]) * factor[i % 2, j % 2]
    return out
```

Looking at the for-loops, it can be easily parallelized:

```py
@njit(parallel=True)
def fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, offset, factor):
    out = np.empty(img.shape, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in prange(img.shape[0]):
        for j in prange(img.shape[1]):
            out[i, j] = (img[i, j] - offset[i % 2, j % 2]) * factor[i % 2, j % 2]
    return out
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
import perfplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
np.random.seed(0)

def fast_transform(img, offset, factor):
    rep = (img.shape[0] // 2, img.shape[1] // 2)
    out = (img.astype(np.float32) - np.tile(offset, rep)) * np.tile(factor, rep)
    return out

img = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 16, 17]])
offset = np.array([[2, 1], [2, 1]])
factor = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 2]])

x = fast_transform(img, factor, offset)
print(x)

# this compiles the function too:
x = fast_transform_numba(img, factor, offset)
print(x)

# this compiles the function too:
x = fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, factor, offset)
print(x)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 255, (n, n), dtype=np.uint8),
    kernels=[
        lambda img: fast_transform(img, offset, factor),
        lambda img: fast_transform_numba(img, offset, factor),
        lambda img: fast_transform_numba_parallel(img, offset, factor),
    ],
    labels=["fast_transform", "fast_transform_numba", "fast_transform_numba_parallel"],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 15)],
    xlabel="img(N * N)",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Creates this graph:

[image]

You can see, that after certain threshold the parallel approach seems to be fastest.