# Quick way to calculate mean around an element in 3d array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I want to calculate the sum around an element in around. For example, calculate the sum of neighboring elements which are within 5 units (in any x,y,z direction). I wrote a loop to do this. This function is to calculate mean of a block in the 3D array. The shape of array is `(159,191,159)` It works ok but because it will be used in another loop, I want to make it run at least one magnitude faster.
How can I use NumPy (or any other way) to make this run more efficient? For example, conditional `np.sum()` I guess? Can anyone give me a simple efficient example to calculate the mean?

```
def patch_mean(coordinate_x,coordinate_y,coordinate_z,image,patch_radius):
    for a in range(coordinate_x- patch_radius, coordinate_x + patch_radius):
        for b in range(coordinate_y - patch_radius, coordinate_y + patch_radius):
            for c in range (coordinate_z - patch_radius, coordinate_z + patch_radius):
              if 0<a<159 and 0<b<191 and 0<c<159:
                 if image[a][b][c] != 0:
                   sum = sum + img[a][b][c]
                   count = count + 1
    if count==0:
        mean=0
    else:
        mean=sum/count
    return mean
```

Comment: I strongly recommend not using `sum` as the name of a variable in python. `sum` is already the name of a builtin function. Shadowing builtins is heavily discouraged. Here is a list of builtins: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a convolution approach.
(However, I am not sure about its performance.)

Here is a simple example for a 2-D array. This example is referenced from the following two articles:
[In numpy, how to efficiently list all fixed-size submatrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414673/in-numpy-how-to-efficiently-list-all-fixed-size-submatrices)
[Convolve2d just by using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086557/convolve2d-just-by-using-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

data = np.arange(48).reshape(6, 8)
```

```
data =
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31]
 [32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]]
```

```
mean_filter_shape = (3, 4)
data_new_shape = tuple(np.subtract(data.shape, mean_filter_shape) + 1) + mean_filter_shape
data_new = as_strided(data, data_new_shape, data.strides * 2)
```

```
data_new = 
[[[[ 0  1  2  3]
   [ 8  9 10 11]
   [16 17 18 19]]
   ...
  [[28 29 30 31]
   [36 37 38 39]
   [44 45 46 47]]]]
```

```
mean_filter = np.ones(mean_filter_shape)
data_mean = np.einsum('ij,klij->kl', mean_filter, data_new) / np.prod(mean_filter_shape)
```

```
data_mean =
[[ 9.5 10.5 11.5 12.5 13.5]
 [17.5 18.5 19.5 20.5 21.5]
 [25.5 26.5 27.5 28.5 29.5]
 [33.5 34.5 35.5 36.5 37.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.signal.convolve` with a `numpy.ones` kernel.

Documentation:

- [scipy.signal.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve);
- [numpy.ones](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve

data = np.random.random((159,191,159))

patch_radius = 5
kernel = np.ones((2*patch_radius+1,2*patch_radius+1,2*patch_radius+1))

data_mean = convolve(data, kernel, mode='same')
```